# react-native run-android giving error without sudo on mac

Tags: react-native, sudo, react-native-cli

How to run react-native without sudo on Mac?

It give me this error every time permission denied.
Is there any solution to run it without sudo?

**Error log**

```
EACCES: permission denied, open '/Me/newone/cc-react- 
native/node_modules/react-native/scripts/.packager.env'
```

Comment: Check the docs for these tools and see if they have an option to install to your own home directory, and don't use `sudo` to install. Other than that, this is probably not quite on topic for this site.